# LINQ checking if an ICollection<int> has any crossover with c# array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

So i have a c# array that contains integers.

In my database i have an entity called request. Request has a one to many relationship with a table called Weeks. In weeks there is a requestID and a week (so week 1 would have value 1, week 2 -> 2 etc.).

I need to construct a where clause that if the database record has any sort of overlap with my c# array, it gets that record.

So for instance, say a request has weeks 1,2,3 connected to it in the database, and my c# array has [3,5,6], i want that request to be pulled.

Any ideas of how to get this done?

this is my current LINQ code so far

```
    IQueryable<request> proposedRequest = db.requests.Include(r => r.rooms);
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.booked.Equals(1));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r => r.roundID.Equals(roundID));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.day.Equals(day));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(s=>s.start<time+length && s.start + s.length > time);
        //I attempted something here but obviously it doesnt work
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>weeks.Contains(r.weeks_request.Any(f=>f.week)));
```

so in my request table there is a attribute weeks. This is either 1 or 0. If it is 1, this means the request is for a standard set of weeks, which is 1-12. This means that there is not an entry in the weeks_request table for this request.

If the weeks attribute is 0, this means that it is any permutation of weeks 1-16, not not the standard 1-12. Therefore there is an individual entry in the weeks_request table for each week selected.

The array weeks contains the weeks that the user wants to book for. But obviously they cannot book a week if it is already booked. Therefore, i need to find if it is already booked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change `r=>weeks.Contains(r.weeks_request.Any(f=>f.week))` to `r=>r.weeks_request.Any(f=>weeks.Contains(f.week))`?

Comment: I believe this may work, ill have a try and get back to you. @JasonBoyd

Comment: I tested something similar on one of my DBs and it seems to work so I went ahead and posted it as a possible answer.

Comment: im having trouble testing it. in my database, request.weeks is either 0 or 1. if it is 1, this means that the weeks selected are 1,2,3...,12. If it is 0, it means there is entries in the weeks_request table containing the selected weeks, so any permutation of 1-16 (for example) but not 1,2,3...,12. Would this still work?

Comment: @JasonBoyd I have added some additional information above, hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try changing:</s>

`r=>weeks.Contains(r.weeks_request.Any(f=>f.week))`

To:

`r=>r.weeks_request.Any(f=>weeks.Contains(f.week))`

**Update based on updated question**

I am not entirely sure I follow what you have going on but try this query:

```
IQueryable<request> proposedRequest = 
    db.requests.Include(r => r.rooms)
    .Where(r => 
        r.booked.Equals(1) &&
        r.roundID.Equals(roundID) &&
        r.day.Equals(day) &&
        r.start < time + length && 
        r.start + r.length > time &&
        ((r.week == 0 && weeks.Any(w => w <= 12) 
            || (r.week == 1 && r.weeks_request.Any(w => weeks.Contains(w.week));
```